# How to install elastic search on linux host server using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, elasticsearch, installation

I am trying to install elastic search on host server in location /usr/local with curl command as below 
`curl -L -O http://download.elasticsearch.org/PATH/TO/VERSION.zip`

But I am getting an error Failed to create file VERSION.zip
I am completely new in using ssh. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -L -O http://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.1.zip
```

You just needed to fill in the path to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting error for this as mentioned earlier "Failed to create the file elasticsearch-1.7.1.zip". Not sure why :(